# get php boolean and change css border color depends on it?

Tags: php, jquery, css

php

```
public function livecheck($check_value, $value){
    global $connection;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE $check_value = ? LIMIT 1";
    $results = $connection->select($query,$value);

    //return total count
    $results_exist = $results->rowCount();
    $results_exist = $results->fetch();

    //if value is more than 0, username is not available
    if($results_exist) {
        //out jquery echo
        echo "We're sorry, that username is not available.";
        //return fail change border to red
        $_exist = true;
    }else{
        echo "username is available.";
        //return true change border to grey
        $_exist = false;
    }
}
```

jquery

```
function checkusername(){
        var username_value = $("#username").val();

            if (username_value.length >= 4){
            //checking the database username exits
            // $("#user-result").html('<img src="imgs/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            // post value isit using it self?//
            $.post('class/validation.php', {'username':username_value}, function(data) {
            $("#user-result").html(data);
            // get the return data from php , fail = red , true = grey
            $("#username").css(data);
            });
        }
        return;
    }
```

this is a live validation checking my database username and my intention is use jquery to change my css border color depends on my php return Boolean , i was able to echo the Boolean data ,so php check if username exists , border = red ,
else border = grey.

i hope i explain it right , i cant figure it out where to start this.

Comment: which result do you get in ````$("#user-result")````. Do you get the boolean there?

Comment: How can you possible think that `.css(data)` will make your border red or green? You aren't even sending those values. Or at least not in the code you showing us.

Comment: oh no no i know how to change the border , but i wanted to depends on the php return , which i dont know where to start , i do that because i think i can somehow pass the ('border-color','red/green') from php to jquery , which wont work i think

Comment: @user3233074 did our answers help you? If so can you please mark the answer correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't just send the `message` from PHP. Send `JSON` object. And depending on the value of `exists` inside object change the colour of the textbox.

PHP:

```
public function livecheck($check_value, $value){
    global $connection;

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE $check_value = ? LIMIT 1";
    $results = $connection->select($query,$value);

    //return total count
    $results_exist = $results->rowCount();
    $results_exist = $results->fetch();

    //if value is more than 0, username is not available
    if($results_exist) {
        //out jquery echo
        $response = array(
            "message"=> "We're sorry, that username is not available.",
            "exist"=> true
        );
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    } else {
        $response = array(
            "message"=> "username is available.",
            "exist"=> false
        );
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Javascript:

```
function checkusername() {
    var username_value = $("#username").val();

    if (username_value.length >= 4) {
        //checking the database username exits
        // $("#user-result").html('<img src="imgs/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        // post value isit using it self?//
        $.post('class/validation.php', {
            'username': username_value
        }, function (data) {
            var usernameAvailable = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#user-result").html(usernameAvailable.message);

            var color = usernameAvailable.exist ? 'gray' : 'red';

            $("#username").css('border-color', color);
        });
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: thank is what i wanted but one small problem , the color do return but when my username available it become red , i tried to switch but seem like  the 2nd color wont work.

Comment: fixed haha mispeling ,thank my friend you are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the variable and the text, so you're going to have to use JSON. You need to change this part in your PHP file:

```
$return = array('text' => '', 'exists' => false);
if($results_exist) {
    //out jquery echo
    //echo "We're sorry, that username is not available.";
    $return['text'] = "We're sorry, that username is not available.";
    //return fail change border to red
    $return['exists'] = true;
}else{
    //echo "username is available.";
    $return['text'] = "username is available.";
    //return true change border to grey
    //$_exist = false;
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Then for your JavaScript:

```
function checkusername(){
    var username_value = $("#username").val();

    if (username_value.length >= 4){
        //checking the database username exits
        // $("#user-result").html('<img src="imgs/ajax-loader.gif" />');
        // post value isit using it self?//
        $.ajax(function() {
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'class/validation.php', 
            data: {'username':username_value}, 
            dataType: 'JSON' //This tells the ajax we're expecting a JSON response.
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            $("#user-result").html(data.text);
            // get the return data from php , fail = red , true = grey
            $("#username").css('border-color', data.exists ? 'grey' : 'red');
        });
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you get the either the values `red` or `grey` returned? In that case you should set the css in the following way:

```
$("#username").css('border-color',data);
```